# Linux and Primesense

Tags: linux, openni, primesense, asus-xtion

I have for a longer time tried to get my Asus Pro Live sensor to work on Linux, currently Fedora, but I have tried ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 13.10 as well. I have installed openni, openni2 and sensor_master on my computer. Everything compiles, but when I try to run NiViewer, all I get is

```
      Could not open "1d27/0600@3/4": Failed to set USB interface!
```

The 55-primesense-usb.rules file is present in /etc/udev/rules.d/ and when I type lsusb it says:

```
      Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1d27:0600 ASUS
```

I have googled for it but cannot find anything helpful. Does anyone have a clue where the problem is?

Some of the output from dmesg:

```
[55363.811218] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[55363.826016] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d27, idProduct=0600
[55363.826018] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[55363.826019] usb 3-4: Product: PrimeSense Device
[55363.826021] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: PrimeSense
[55363.826609] usb 3-4: Not enough bandwidth for new device state.
[55363.826614] usb 3-4: can't set config #1, error -28
[56819.384811] usb 3-3: USB disconnect, device number 5
```

I have tried both usb 2.0 and 3.0 and it works in windows.

/ Erik

Comment: Do you have USB error messages in `dmesg`? The Xtion seems to have problems with USB 3.0.

Comment: It seems like the bandwidth is not enough?

Comment: This is what I was referring to: http://www.pcl-developers.org/xhci-hcd-I-hate-you-USB-3-0-and-Primesense-Asus-Xtion-td5707949.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Asus Pro, like any other webcam, needs to reserve USB bandwidth, and this should be adaptive depending on the actual capture resolution and bandwidth, but that is not always the case: many WebCams, like [Logitech C910](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/hd-pro-webcam-c910) "preventively" reserve a chunk of USB capacity large enough to prevent other webcams from using it. The UVC driver, which is pervasively used in Linux knows about this under the feared `I get a "No space left on device" (-28) error when trying to stream from more than one camera simultaneously.`, see [UVC driver FAQ](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/faq/). This seems to be your issue. Trying to connect the cameras in your system in different USB port configurations can help.

Comment: Hi, yes I have gotten it to work now. The solution is to deactivate xHCI in BIOS. In my case it did not help to change USB-port, but I guess that differs from computer to computer.